# C# inheritance classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to solve a task, but I don't get how to create Add class so that the program works correctly.

I have checked many posts, but haven't found a solution. I try to own public for Number, Text, .... but in Visual Studio tips always ask to create public int new Number in class `Class : Add`.

I know I should create a list where I can add it text and number then if number then parse...or should I use indexers?

```
class Add
{
    //...............
}

class Class : Add
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int NumberPlusOne()
    {
        return Number + 1;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number is " + Number);
        Console.WriteLine("Text is " + Text);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Add add = new Class();
        add.Number = 123;
        add.Text = "Hello!";
        add.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Number + 1 = " + add.NumberPlusOne());
    }
}
```

Comment: `public abstract class Add {...}` // note "abstract"

Comment: `class Class` really?

Comment: ...no need to comment like That Ian.. its not about name but the way how to solve and you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//This is my solution

```
interface Add
        {
            string text { get; set; }
            int number { get; set; }
            void Print();
            int NumberPlusOne();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: a base *abstract* class (`Add`) and *derived* class (`Class`) that *overrides* abstract methods

```
  // note "abstract"
  public abstract class Add {
    public abstract int Number { get; set; }
    public abstract string Text { get; set; }
    public abstract int NumberPlusOne(); 
    public abstract void Print();
  }
```

And `Class` should be changed into

```
  // note "override"
  class Class : Add {
     public override int Number { get; set; }
     public override string Text { get; set; }

     public override int NumberPlusOne()
     {
         return Number + 1;
     }

     public override void Print()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Number is " + Number);
         Console.WriteLine("Text is " + Text);
     }
  }
```

Comment: hmmm.... i need to solve this problem only adding Add class withiout changing other parts... but i tried your suggestion and still having problem in main add.NumberPlusOne(), --> VS suggest to generate abstract method in Add, but then i implement Abstract Class and having problem type Class already defines a member called  NumberPlusOne with the same parameter types....

Comment: Sorry, I haven´t seen `add.NumberPlusOne()`; in that case you have to add `public abstract int NumberPlusOne();` into `Add` class and *override* it in the `Class`: `public override int NumberPlusOne()
     {
         return Number + 1;
     }`. See my edit

Comment: yeah, working perfectly, Is there another way to solve this task without using override in Class: Add???